# How to view specific rows that my logistic regression has classified

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am currently working on a logistic regression model to predict the outcome of certain trades. This model classifies trades in the test set as good/bad (1/0). I want to see which trades are being classified in each group and multiply the trades classified as "good" by its profit/loss to find out if the logistic regression model is actually profitable. Is there any way I am able to view row-specific info of the entries that the model classifies as True/False?

This is what my code looks like for my data scaling and splitting into train/test set:

```
x = df[x_train_features]
y = df["y"]
y = y.astype("int")


# scale data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaledx = scaler.fit_transform(x)


# split training data into test and training sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaledx, y, test_size=0.25)

# instantiate the model (using the default parameters)
logreg = LogisticRegression()


# fit the model with data
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred_test = (logreg.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1] >= 0.5).astype(bool)
```

I tried to use `df.loc[y_pred_test == True]`, but I get the error:

```
Boolean index has wrong length: 720 instead of 2880
```

most likely because the test set is smaller than the whole sample set.

Comment: I think you missed the step where you add a new column to your `df` with the predictions to use `df.loc` method.

Comment: I tried adding a column too but the lengths dont match since the test set is much smaller than the whole dataframe. I'm not sure if theres a way to only add the boolean values to the rows within the test set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you haven't concatenated your prediction values with the df.
You might try this:

```
y_pred_test = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_test)
X_test = pd.concat([y_test, y_pred_test], axis =1)
```

This will combine your prediction values with the ground truth.
Then you can try the following:

```
X_test.iloc[y_pred_test == True]
```

And as you haven't predicted on the whole dataset (df) that's why you are getting the error that the number of rows in y_pred_test are 720 and not 2880.

Comment: Hmm I tried using pd.concat() with y_test but I keep getting "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects". Additionally, wouldn't this only allow me to access the "y" values? I was hoping there was a way to access the rows from the original dataset that the model classified.

Comment: If you want to access y values then you need to model.predict() on y_train as well. Then combine pd.DataFrame(y_pred_train) and pd.DataFrame(y_pred_test) and then combine it with the df. Then you can access that.

Comment: Also to access a specific row from the dataframe, you can use df.iloc[index] (change the index value with the specific row that you want to see). Also, When you call loc with a scalar value, you get a pd.Series. That series will then have one dtype. If you want to see the row as it is in the dataframe, you'll want to pass an array like indexer to loc.

Wrap your index value with an additional pair of square brackets

print(df.loc[[123]])

Comment: Sorry what I meant was I wanted to access the other column values in the original dataframe. As I have a column "PnL" that tracks profit/losses, I wanted to multiply the classifier by the PnL to see what the actual gains/losses would be if the trade was executed according to the model. I was thinking about combining pred_y_train and pred_y_test, but since I used train_test_split to split the data, wouldn't it shuffle the rows, making it impossible to concatenate with the original df?

Comment: No it won't shuffle unless you shuffled it before. But even if you shuffled them, still it wont affect the values in that perticular row. You are shuffling means that you are only changing the order of all the rows. And if you concatenate then the values of a row will stays the same

Comment: Oh I think I actually figured it out. Rather than concatenating the y_pred_test data with y_test, I concatenated with dataframe(X_test) so that I would only be looking at the rows within the test set. From there I just renamed the columns and used those values for my calculations. Thank you!

Comment: That was my first answer. But it's great that you figured out by yourself. And you are welcome

Comment: Ahh I think there was just a typo in the answer being to concat y_test instead of X_test, but it makes a lot more sense now!